# Auto-play directory of music videos

Tags: boot, linux, vlc

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B as a car stereo head unit.  It works great with a Hi-Fi audio hat and touchscreen.  I'd like to make it automatically play the directory of music videos on any attached flash drive.  I know I can do this with VLC as

```
vlc "directory of videos"
```

I have figured out I can make this happen on boot by placing a script in the init.d directory.  Where I need help is: how can I write a Linux script that can look at all mounted media in the /media/ directory for a subfolder called "Music" where I would have the music videos?  I use multiple flash drives and rather than hardcoding one, I'd like to make it work regardless of what drive I happened to insert.

Thank you if you can help.

Comment: what is the problem specifically?  ... `how can I write a Linux script?` has an answer `use a text editor`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @jsotola I guess you missed the sentence: "I'd like to make it automatically play the directory of music videos on any attached flash drive."  Let me know if you need any more help with comprehending that.

Comment: @CodyRiggle that is a description of what you would like to do ... it is not a description of the problem that you are facing ... in other words, why are your attempts not succeeding?